# Slow down the speed of a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, delay

I need to slow down the execution speed of for loop. I have to increase the width of the div slowly.

So far i have tried `delay(),setTimeout(),setInterval()` but without success. They all seem to behave in the same way.

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div class="divclass">

    </div>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var width = $('.divclass').width();
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        width = width + 20;
        $('.divclass').delay(2000);
        $(".divclass").css("width", width);
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RQVa8/1/

Can anyone show me where my mistake lies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use animation instead of loop

Comment: Have a look at `setInterval()`. jQuery's `.delay()` will only have an effect on the animation queue.

Comment: may be you r looking for animate

Comment: You can't slow down a for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/RQVa8/3/)

[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) documentation

```
$(".divclass").animate({width: width}, 2000);
```

Comment: its better to set the easing to "linear" for a smoother animation. $(".divclass").animate({width: width}, 2000, "linear");

Comment: @s4ty Everything we can't cover here.Documentation link covers all :)

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for this.

```
$(".divclass").animate({ "width": "+=20" }, 2000);
```

See the section about `+=` to use relative values:

> Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with
>   a leading `+=` or `-=` sequence of characters, then the target value is
>   computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current
>   value of the property.

Comment: I thought about suggesting '$(".divclass").animate({ "width": "+=20" }, 2000);' ;-)